# GCS bucket to Snowflake Stage data transfer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We are creating a storage integration and the then creating a stage with this storage integration. For this we have STORAGE_PROVIDER = ‘GCS’ from GCP,
so for this we are getting a **service account** created by snowflake automatically, is there a way we can use our own service account or create a new one and replace it with the snowflake created service account?

Comment: we have come to know that Private Connectivity to Snowflake Internal Stages is currently not supported on GCP.

Comment: I'd love to know: Why is the service account not a good solution for you?

Comment: because its not a private account, its the account which created by snowflake

Answer (score 2):

we have come to know that Private Connectivity to Snowflake Internal Stages is currently not supported on GCP